# Location simulation locked up

Tags: gps, codenameone

Today, when I try to use the location simulation, I find it is unresponsive.
Prior to this, I was able to resize the simulator, and go to any location. Today, none of these inputs work.

Also, is it possible to change the default lat/long in the simulator? 
It currently defaults to a location that is not very useful to me.

Thanks,
 -Craig Lang
  Horizon Technologies

Comment: Are you working with the Codename One source code or with the releases? If the former this might be a regression due to this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sql-explorer-global-toolbar-location-docs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default location by entering your desired Latitude and Longitude to the fields provided and Update, then close the location window.

Whenever you run app, it will now default to that location. I agree that location simulation should remember your last used location when it's opened and it shouldn't change the default to New York. I believe this is something Codenameone team could provide.

Your location simulation maybe freezing if you're using the update Piotr provided, as it may contain minor bug. Check if you are getting any Exception in your console.

Comment: I'm using the releases.

Comment: The simulator puts up an exception any time I try to move the map or click on 'Update".

Comment: @shai,
I'm using the released code. But I think Eclipse did an update in the last few days.

I get an exception any time I try to move the map or click on 'Update". Here are the top four lines in the trace.

Exception in runnable:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Clipboard.putContent: null data
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.putContent(Unknown Source)
 at javafx.scene.input.Clipboard.setContent(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you type anything into the location fields? Try tapping on the map component before dragging to set a location.

Comment: Yes I had entered a latitude and longitude, then presses update

Comment: Also I believe I did click on the map.  I remember because it didn't redraw when I resized the window

Comment: If you respond with a comment to an entry I didn't write or comment on I don't get a notification so I didn't see any of these. The stack trace you included is cropped can you provide the full stack trace in the original question by editing your question and posting it there? Then add a comment below that question so I will get a notification that something changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these pull request are solutions:

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/1703
https:/github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/1707

The first one added all locations parameters to the form and remove update button as not needed, you need just change value or move you mouse wheel.
 This pull request was accepted free days ago so it should be on production?
The second one add store form fields and waiting for accept.

[New Location Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4eOm.jpg)

Comment: So this would be in the build? Or would I need to be using the source code to get it?

Comment: I hope it will be available after next update of CN1 libraries but I don't know when it will be done,

Comment: Wasn't able to get back to this for a few weeks. Downloaded the build update on 3/29/16 at 1:45PM CDT. Again tried the location simulation. I still see the same problem. When I enter a new latitude and longitude and press the Update button, there is no change to the display, or to the latitude and longitude on the bottom status bar. In addition, attempting to drag the map to a new location has no response. It looks like the UI for this is completely non-functional. I'm wondering if there is some configuration problem I'm overlooking.

Comment: Another thought. Is there a particular version of Java now needed to run CN1 on eclipse? Especially to run the simulator? I am currently using Java JDK version 1.7.0_71. 

Eclipse had a problem when I tried to upgrade Java some time ago, so I stuck with 1.7.

Comment: Updated Java to version SDK 1.8.0_77, which appears to be the most current version according to java.com.
Restarted eclipse and CN1 simulator with location simulator. No change to the observed behavior. Location UI does not accept user input